# Unable to overwrite directory in Pacman

Tags: pacman-package-manager

I am about to install a package, but it keeps failing because the file already exists. Since `--force` option is removed from pacman. I have been trying to overwrite the directory by `--overwrite` option but unfortunately, this option is also not working

**Command I ran:** `sudo pacman -S namcap --overwrite /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elftools/elf/*`

### Conflicting Files

```
....
python-pyelftools: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elftools/elf/notes.py exists in filesystem
python-pyelftools: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elftools/elf/relocation.py exists in filesystem
python-pyelftools: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elftools/elf/sections.py exists in filesystem
python-pyelftools: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elftools/elf/segments.py exists in filesystem
python-pyelftools: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elftools/elf/structs.py exists in filesystem
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pacman -S <package> --overwrite=*`

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain how this exactly works and why `$ sudo pacman -S <package> --overwrite /path/to/package` wasn't working for me? It was generating the same error as above in op's case...